# insertar div en css?

Tags: html, css

Necesito insertar una etiqueta  dentro de css para que me pueda generar la fuente selecionada, pero no consigo hacerlo aquí dejo el codigo...

```html
<style>



   
  
    @font-face {
  font-family: "marsneveneksk2";
   
  src: url("../fuentes/bubble.ttf"); <- aquí queria introducir la etiqueta div , pero no lo consigo :(
  }
  
  
          fuente{
  font-family: "marsneveneksk2", cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #696;
   color: #666;
  
  


  
}
</style>



<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="bubble.ttf">bubble</option>    
<option value="marsneveneksk1">marsneveneksk 1</option>    
<option value="marsneveneksk2">marsneveneksk 2</option>    
<option value="nosed">Nosed</option>    
<option value="painterz">Painterz</option>   
<option value="bombing">bombing</option>
<option value="ruthlessrrippin1">ruthlessrrippin1</option>
<option value="ruthlessWreckin2">ruthlessWreckin2</option>
<option value="sickcapital-vice">sickcapital vice1</option>
<option value="sickcapitalvice">sickcapital vice2</option>
<option value="graffogie">Graffogie</option>
<option value="mostwasted">Mostwasted</option>
<option value="whoa">Whoa!</option>
<option value="subway">Subway</option>
<option value="gta">GTA</option>
<option value="nextcustom">Next Custom</option>
<option value="bboy">B-Boy</option>
<option value="somebubbles">Some Bubbles</option>
<option value="fontbubble">Font Bubble</option>
<option value="supergraf">Super Graf</option>
<option value="aerosol">AeroSol</option>
<option value="crime">crime</option>
<option value="mifuente">Mi Fuente</option>

</select>





<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "" + x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: No soy capaz de entender que es lo que estás preguntando. ¿Insertar un elemento html dentro de css? Además estaría bien que trataras de formatear un poco el código que pegas para que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: No tiene sentido insertar código html dentro de un código css, los que normalmente se hace es modificar el estilo css de un elemento html por medio de un evento de javascript como se muestra en el ejemplo [JavaScript HTML DOM - Changing CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: no es un div, es un style tendrías que precargar los archivos de las fuentes luego hacer algo como lo que se muestra en https://stackoverflow.com/a/11355234/1423096

Comment: Perdona, soy algo nuevo en esto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro sobre los nombres de tus fonts, pero creo que esto te puede servir.

```js
$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <button>erase</button>
    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Blackletter">Blackletter</option>
        <option value="Comic Sans">Comic Sans</option>
        <option value="Impact ">Impact </option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    </select>
    
    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br/>

<textarea class="changeMe">Text into textarea</textarea>
<div id="container" class="changeMe">
    <div id="float">
        <p>
            Text into container
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Revisar [answer].

Comment: Muchas gracias, por gran ayuda :D